# The search for a set of points with a minimum sum of lengths to rectangles. What is the algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, computational-geometry

Good day.

I have the task of finding the set of points in 2D space for which the sum of the distances to the rectangles is minimal. For example, for two rectangles, the result will be the next area ([picture](https://i.ibb.co/7jS8K7F/rects.png)). Any point in this area has the minimum sum of lengths to A and B rectangles.
Which algorithm is suitable for finding a **region**, all points of which have the minimum sum of lengths? The number of rectangles can be different, they are randomly located. They can even overlap each other. The sides of the rectangles are parallel to the coordinate axes and cannot be rotated. The **region** must be either a rectangle or a line or a point.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: This problem seems quite straightforward to implement in a trivial way, while it may not be the most efficient one but what have you done so far? Where is your real problem?

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Computational Science Stack Exchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @JonnyHenly this context does not qualify for the message you used, because it is not asking for any of those, it's actually asking for a software algorithm, which is permitted [according to the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Ar the rectangles aligned as in the picture, or can they be rotated? How do you represent the point set (e.g. as a polygon)?

Comment: @Daniel The [Help Center -> Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page that you link states *"Some questions are still off-topic, **even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**"*, below the unordered list which includes software algorithms.

Comment: @JonnyHenly While that's true, however it's on the list of generally appropriate questions AND it's not on the list of off-topic questions.

Comment: @Daniel I consider algorithms to be tools used by programmers, therefore this question is asking us to **recommend or find a tool**. I don't have a problem with someone asking a question about an algorithm, as long as they show what they have researched/tried. I do have a problem with someone basically saying "I don't feel like researching this, what's the answer?"

Comment: @JonnyHenly, The task is to find an area (rectangle) with points for which the sum of the lengths to the other rectangles is minimal. Due to the fact that I need to find the minimum sum of lengths to the rectangles, and not to specific points, I determine the zone in which there is exactly a solution and find the point by iteration.

Comment: @Jack, my problem is that I'm not very good at math.

Comment: @Beta, Rectangles can not be rotated, but can overlap each other.. A set of points can be squares, rectangles, straight lines and a point.

Comment: @Jack: could you please explain the trivial solution ?

Comment: for each pair of rectangles, first you sort them placing the topmost-leftmost first, then you check if they overlap (`x1+w1 > x2 && y1+h1 > y1`) then if they overlap you just need to calculate the rectangle between them which is still easy since it starts at `xr = std::max(x1, x2)` and ends at `xe = std::min(x1+w1, x2+w2)` for each coordinate.

Comment: @Jack: this works with this particular figure. What with three rectangles ?

Comment: Actually from the description is not clear how this should work for 3+ rectangles, how would you find a set of points for which the distance is minimal compared to what? Any point in space has a sum of distances to the all rectangles, with no constraint on this set of points the problem makes no sense.

Comment: @Jack: for every point of the plane, the sum of the distances to all rectangles is well defined. This function has one or more global minima. There is no reason that you can answer for two rectangles but cannot for three.

Comment: It is unclear if you mean the distance to the whole rectangle area, or just the rectangle outline. And how do you compute the global distance in case of overlapping rectangles ?

Comment: "The region must be either a rectangle or a line or a point": one can very well imagine geometries such that the solution is made of to distinct lines.

Comment: @Jack, there are 2 ways to determine the length between points. If the point is on the side of the rectangle ([pic](https://i.ibb.co/Rg627Xg/ttt.png) A and C) then the length is at right angles. If the point is located from the rectangle diagonally ([pic](https://i.ibb.co/Rg627Xg/ttt.png) B and D).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The distance map of a rectangle (function that maps any point (x,y) to the closest distance to the rectangle) is made of four slanted planes (slope 45°), four quarter of cones and the rectangle itself, which is at ground level, forming a continuous surface.

To obtain the global distance map, it "suffices" to sum the distance maps of the individual rectangles. A pretty complex surface will result. Depending on the geometries, the minimum might be achieved on a single vertex, a whole edge or a whole face.

The construction of the global map seems more difficult than that of a [line arrangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrangement_of_lines), due to the conic patches. A very difficult problem in the general case, though the axis-aligned constraint might ease it.

Answer (score 1):

Add on Yves's answer.

As Yves described, each rectangle 'divide' plane into 9 parts and adds different distance method in to the sum. Middle part (rectangle) add distance 0, side parts add coordinate distance to that side, corner parts add point distance to that corner. With that approach plan has to be divided into 9^n parts, and distance sum is calculated by adding appropriate rectangle distance functions. That is feasible if number of rectangles is not too large.

Probably it is not needed to calculate all parts since it is easy to calculate some bound on part min value and check is it needed to calculate part at all.

I am not sure, but it seems to me that global distance map is convex function. If that is the case than it can be solved iteratively by similar idea as in linear programming.